# Whats with the zeroes in my binary file?

Tags: c, linux, fwrite

So. I have been experimenting with fwrite().

On my system sizeof( int ) = 4.
I have an array of ints that contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

When i write it to a binaryfile and view it with hexdump I get:

```
0000000 0001 0000 0002 0000 0003 0000 0004 0000
0000010 0005 0000 0006 0000                    
0000018
```

Whats does it write zeroes between the 4byte values?

Comment: This question title is kind of hilarious - would you prefer a binary file of just 1's?

Comment: Write the number 3735928559 to your file and see what you get. You won't find a single numeric value in your hexdump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how big a byte is in your output - 8 bits require two hexadecimal digits to be completely represented.  One single `int` from your example is:

```
0001 0000
```

You might want to display as 32-bit data (or 8-bit data) rather than 16.  That's what makes your dump look weird.

I duplicated your binary file and ran `od` with a few different options.  Hopefully you find the example enlightening:

```
$ od -t x4 example
0000000          00000001        00000002        00000003        00000004
0000020          00000005        00000006                                
0000030
$ od -t x2 example 
0000000      0001    0000    0002    0000    0003    0000    0004    0000
0000020      0005    0000    0006    0000                                
0000030
$ od -t x1 example 
0000000    01  00  00  00  02  00  00  00  03  00  00  00  04  00  00  00
0000020    05  00  00  00  06  00  00  00                                
0000030
```

As you can see best from the 1- and 4-byte examples, I'm also on a little-endian machine, like you.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that it was nibbles. The endianess confused me further.

Comment: od -t x4 makes perfect sense. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Because 1 (for example) represented as 4-byte hex is `00000001`.  Apparently you're on a [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system, hence the apparently back-to-front ordering when you inspect your file.

Answer (score 3):

Your hexdump is grouping two bytes as a single word and changing the endianness. On most systems, using `hexdump -C` changes the dump into canonical view which prevents the grouping. In hexadecimal, one character represents one nybble, and there are two nybbles per byte. So your 4-byte `int` should have 8 nybbles in total. Since your numbers are very small, most of your nybbles are 0.